# Proper way to turn off PWM channel on STM32

Tags: stm32, pwm

I am using STM32F4 to drive a 3 phase BLDC motor and i'm using TIM1 peripheral to 
generate 6-step PWM(complementary pwm) but when i change the configuration and i disable 1 channel it takes some time to go low which causing problems (you can check the photos in the links below )

https://ibb.co/fv3PGJ0
https://ibb.co/6sTsYDM
https://ibb.co/MkFLttv
also here is my configuration:

```
TIM1->PSC=0;
TIM1->ARR=800;          
TIM1->CCR1=400;
TIM1->CCR2=400;
TIM1->CCR3=400;
TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_2 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2PE | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_2; 
TIM1->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC3PE | TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_1 | TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_2 ;
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E | TIM_CCER_CC1NE | TIM_CCER_CC2E | TIM_CCER_CC2NE | TIM_CCER_CC3E | TIM_CCER_CC3NE ;//!CH and CH
TIM1->CR2 |= TIM_CR2_OIS1N | TIM_CR2_OIS2N | TIM_CR2_OIS3N | TIM_CR2_CCPC ;
TIM1->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE | TIM_BDTR_OSSR;
TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_DIR; // DOWN COUNTER
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
```

and this the code to change the config:

```
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
TIM1->CCER &=~ ( TIM_CCER_CC2E | TIM_CCER_CC3E | TIM_CCER_CC3NE);
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1NE | TIM_CCER_CC1E; //AH + !AH
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC2NE;//BL
```

is there a way to turn off both complementary pwm at the same time

Comment: Write to the entire register, not the bit fields.

Comment: i'm using the TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_COMG command , so it will execute only when this bit COMG is high

Comment: So then what's the problem? You can't write CCxE and CCxNE and then use COMG to trigger them to both update? Or did I misunderstand? I thought the problem was that you couldn't shut them down at the same time. Is that not the problem?

Comment: Re-reading your post, it is not clear which is your problem. "*to turn off both complementary pwm at the same time" and"*it takes some time to go low which causing problems*" are two different issues. Are you having trouble turning them off at the same time? Or turning them off immediately?

Comment: the code above is only for 1 step, and there 6 steps ( 3 half bridges and 6 pwm), and i need in every step one bridge to be completly off ( so 2 pwm are low)

Comment: Oh, I see. yeah. Use Break for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *TIM_CR2_CCPC* bit set, which makes *CCxE*, *CCxNE* and *OCxM* bits preloaded. The actual bits are updated when a COM event occurs. So I guess you need `TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_COMG;` after changing those bits.

However, disabling the output may not be the correct thing to do. Please consider updating *CCxM* bits to *0b100* or *0b101*, which forces them to inactive or active levels.

Comment: if i change the CCXM to 0b100 then 1 channel will be the opposite the other sinse they are complementary but i need the two channels to go low

Answer (score 4):

This is what the Break functionality is for, as the reference below says

> Break input to put the timer’s output signals in reset state or in a known state.
>
> The break can be generated by the BRK input which has a programmable polarity and an
> enable bit BKE in the TIMx_BDTR Register.
> There are two solutions to generate a break:
> • By using the BRK input which has a programmable polarity and an enable bit BKE in
> the TIMx_BDTR register
> • By software through the BG bit of the TIMx_EGR register.

See 17.3.12 of the [reference manual RM0090](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/3d/6d/5a/66/b4/99/40/d4/DM00031020.pdf/files/DM00031020.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00031020.pdf)

Comment: I will try it !!

Answer (score 1):

like Tagli said it's better to change CCxM than disabling the output but there is a case 
where you need the 2 channels (complentary pwm )to be low. so the solution for this is to change the polarity of one channel by setting CCxNP bit in the CCER register here is the modification in the code ( this part is only for 1 step)

```
TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_2 ; 
TIM1->CCMR1 |=  TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_2 ;
TIM1->CCMR1 &=~  TIM_CCMR1_OC2M_1 ;

TIM1->CCMR2 |= TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_2 ;
TIM1->CCMR2 &=~ TIM_CCMR2_OC3M_1 ;
TIM1->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC3NP;
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_COMG;
```

or you can do this instead

```
TIM1->CCMR1=0x00004868;
TIM1->CCMR2=0x00000048;
TIM1->CCER=0x00000D55 ;
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_COMG;
```